# jquery plugin for horizontal image sliding with a slider that can be moved by the user

Tags: jquery, slider

[image: Slider Requirement]

Hi guys,
I have a slider element as shown in the image. When I slide the slider, 
(1) the image carousel should rotate in a circular manner
(2) The farther the slider from the center the greater the speed of rotation

Any sample jquery code or plugin? Any help is appreciated. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Used this plugin. It has many custom methods like play, pause which can be used according to the slider movement. http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/ Thanks:)